# jquery validation min method usage problem

Tags: jquery, validation

i am using [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) validation plugin. And trying to use the min method validation. It works ok but I want to the exclude the minimum value I have provided , so I added Number.MIN_VALUE to it.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      min: 13 +  Number.MIN_VALUE
    }
  }
});
```

But this doesn't make a difference and  13 is not excluded . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: huh what do you want the min to be ?

Comment: i want the input to accept values greater than but NOT equal to 13 . the jquery help about this says "To exclude the minimum value, add Number.MIN_VALUE to that value." here : [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value)

Comment: @karantis clearly, that documentation page is simply wrong :-)

Comment: there are not many days when one get to say the jQuery documentation got something wrong :) haha . Will go for making my own function then, Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

When you try and form a floating-point value from MIN_VALUE plus 13, you exhaust the representational capacity of the format and end up with 13. In other words, `13 + Number.MIN_VALUE` is essentially `13`.

```
alert(13 === (13 + Number.MIN_VALUE)); // alerts "true"
```

You could always write your own validation add-on that does a pure ">" comparison instead of ">=".

*edit* — I have a hard time recommending this, but you might try:

```
  min: 13.000000000000002
```

That's the next largest 64-bit IEE 754 value (as decimal) after 13 that can be represented. [This page](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/) is primitive but handy.

Comment: I know I could have mafe my own validation function, see the link in my comment on @mcgrailm . I thought it was possible.

Comment: Well the problem is that if the code for the "min" validation is doing a ">=" test, you're sort-of stuck. I'll edit my answer however.